# Bootstrap pagination style is not applied to code

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pagination

I am developing site in codeigniter and using pagination library i set up pagination...

But Bootstrap class is not applied to that pagination so pagination is looking messy.. I am not having any error though...

I also have linked a bootstrap file (Because it's not showing error in console).. I also tried bootstrap CDN.. but still it's not working.. can anyone show me what i am missing...

this is the website: => 
http://dev.cctvbuzz.com

and this is the code..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="pagination">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li class="page"><a href="http://dev.cctvbuzz.com/index.php/home/index/14" data-ci-pagination-page="2">2</a></li>
      <li class="page"><a href="http://dev.cctvbuzz.com/index.php/home/index/28" data-ci-pagination-page="3">3</a></li>
      <li class="page"><a href="http://dev.cctvbuzz.com/index.php/home/index/42" data-ci-pagination-page="4">4</a></li>
      <li class="next page"><a href="http://dev.cctvbuzz.com/index.php/home/index/14" data-ci-pagination-page="2" rel="next">Next →</a></li>
      <li class="next page"><a href="http://dev.cctvbuzz.com/index.php/home/index/322" data-ci-pagination-page="24">Last »</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to something like this.
Add the following css rules.

```
li {
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Or something like this. add `.pagination` class in `ul`

```
<ul class="pagination">
  ..... 
 </ul>
```

Comment: This worked.. But why bootstrap css class is not applied.. i mean i want the same style as bootstrap provide..Any thoughts?

Comment: In boostrap use .pagination>li>a class for pagination. But in html structure use .pagination>ul>li>a  structure. So, i think this is not working but i am not sure.

Comment: Also i have add another case for bootstrap css use this if you have use all bootstrap class

Comment: Hey.. Got one problem... It only works if i add bootstrap CDN "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
I want to change its color from blue to red to suit my website template..
I saw the code from inspect element which it gets from pagination.less file..

Any solution for that?

Comment: If you want to set different color then try to somehing like this .pagination>li>a{color: red;}